# How to prove the solution of an inequality is lower bounded?

Tags: inequality

Let $x_{n,k}\in (0,1]$ be **any** solution of the following inequality
\begin{align}
n(1-x)^2+2kx^2(1-x)^2 -x^2-k(1-x)^4 \leq 0,
\end{align}
where $n, k$ are parameters such that $n\geq k\geq 1$.
I want to prove that there exists a **strictly positive** constant $c$ (i.e. $c>0$) such that
\begin{align}
x_{n,k} \geq c, \text{ for all } n\geq k \geq 1.
\end{align}

If you want to have a look at their graphs, they are available [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=n*%281-x%29%5E2%2B2*k*x%5E2%281-x%29%5E2+-x%5E2-k*%281-x%29%5E4+where+n%3D4%2C+k%3D3+) thanks to Wolfram Alpha.

I tried a lot of estimations, but failed.
I guess that we should use something special here.
Could someone give me a hint? Thanks!

Comment: If $n=k$ then $x=0$ is a solution.

Comment: @Kavi Ah it is my typo, actually, we consider only positive solutions.

Comment: @no perhaps, my question is not clear. Let $S_{n,k}\subset (0,1]$ be the set of solutions. The question is whether the collection $S_{n,k}$ is lower bounded by a strictlypositive constant. any way, thank for your disvussion.

Comment: @Leon, shouldn't it be $x_{n,k} \geq c, \forall x_{n,k} \in S_{n,k}$ then? because I think the other way around implies $x_{n,k}$ is a solution for multiples values of $n,k$? I could be wrong however...

Comment: yes exactly, I want to prove $x\geq c$ for all $x\in S_{n,k}$ and $c$ is independent of $n$ and $k$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(x) = n(1-x)^2+2kx^2(1-x)^2 -x^2-k(1-x)^4$.

We have, for all $x$ in $(0, 1]$,
\begin{align}
f(x) &\ge k(1-x)^2 + 0 - x^2 - k(1-x)^4 \\
&= k[(1-x)^2 - (1-x)^4] - x^2\\
&\ge (1-x)^2 - (1-x)^4 - x^2 \\
&\ge (1-x)^2 - (1-x)^3 - x^2 \\
&= x(x^2 - 3x + 1).
\end{align}
Thus, if $x\in (0, 1]$ satisfying $f(x) \le 0$, then
$x^2 - 3x + 1 \le 0$ which results in $\frac{3 - \sqrt{5}}{2} \le x \le 1$.

We are done.

Comment: Wao, the estimation is indeed amazing! Thank you so much!

Comment: @Leon You are welcome.